# Delphi 2010: Form OnKeyDown, OnKeyPress or OnKeyUp doesn't work at all when using OpenGL!

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-2010

I have a form and I've passed its handle to the OpenGL class to draw. I want to get keyboard commands from the user but it seems the procedures for getting the keys doesn't run (I've tested it). Although, I am using OnMouseDown with no problem at all.

Is there anything I am missing here? Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been ages since I used VCL (with C++Builder 3), but if it's still the same as in the old days, you might want to set `KeyPreview` on your form to `True`. That will cause the form to receive events that normally would only go to controls.

Comment: Wow...Thanks a lot man! I didn't know that this property for the forms even existed!!... I should really reconsider my visual programming skills. :)
You absolutely made my day. Thank you.